# Defining opentype fonts for beamer themes

Tags: beamer, font-encodings

I am working to adapt the jhsph beamer theme (https://github.com/jfiksel/jhsphbeamer ) to work more generally for other JHU departments, ideally making the theme at least approximate JHU's "official" font families (https://brand.jhu.edu/typography/ ).

I've made a lot of progress but am having trouble getting a few of the fonts to work right.

Using lualatex and fontspec, I can do:

```
\newfontfamily\quadonmed{Quadon Medium}
\newfontfamily\arnhem{Arnhem Pro Bln}
\newfontfamily\arnbold{Arnhem Pro Bold}
...
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\quadonmed}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{family=\quadonmed}
```

and this works for *some* of the templates: frametitle, framesubtitle, item, itemize/enumerate body, itemize/enumerate subbody, itemize/enumerate subsubbody . But it does *not* work for title, subtitle, author, institute, date, or (most problematically) structure or normal text.

I can get normal text to display in the correct font by the following kludge:

`\setsansfont{Arnhem Pro Bln}`

but that then renders all text, including title and subtitle, in that font.

I've not had much luck finding documentation or examples that use the `\setbeamerfont` commands in detail, so would appreciate your help or pointers.

Updating 2/3/22: Here's a MWE:
beamerthemeJHUKSAS.sty:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatextra}
%\usefonttheme{professonalfonts}

% Use Helvetica, as requested
%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

%For some reason this is the only way I can get the regular body text
% to show up in Arnhem. 
%\setsansfont{Arnhem Pro Bln}

%This seems to work but want to tweak the specific elements. Take a look at
% http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf
% for more on each element. As of now the normal text one isn't working
\newfontfamily\quadonxb{Quadon ExtraBold}
\newfontfamily\quadonmed{Quadon Medium}
\newfontfamily\arnhem{Arnhem Pro Bln}
\newfontfamily\arnbold{Arnhem Pro Bold}

%%Arrgh, the title page isn't reading these commands for some reason!
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\quadonmed}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\quadonmed}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{family=\quadonmed}
\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\arnhem}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\arnhem}
\setbeamerfont{block}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamerfont{item}{family=\arnbold}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{parent=itemize/enumerate body}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{parent=itemize/enumerate subbody}
\setbeamerfont{description body}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{parent=title}
\setbeamerfont{author}{parent=title}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{parent=title}
\setbeamerfont{date}{parent=title}
```

mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[slides]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,url,comment}

\usetheme{JHUKSAS}

\mode<handout>{\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border
    shrink=5mm]\setbeameroption{show notes}}

\title{Minimal Working Example (MWE)}
\date{Sociology 101}
\author{Andrew J. Perrin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \note{~}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The title will be rendered correctly but}
  This text is not going to show up right
  \begin{itemize}
  \item and this will be fine
  \end{itemize}
  \note{~}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would be easier to figure out what the problem is if you [posted a MWE.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) At a glance: if you included the original theme and then added your own commands afterward, that theme redefines `\normalfamily` as `\sffamily`, which might be why all the styles change when you `\setsansfont`. You almost surely do want to, instead of loading the obsolete `helvet` package.

Comment: Thanks - but what I'm trying to do is use different font families for titles from those for body text, so redefining \normalfamily (or via \setsansfont) doesn't work since it makes everything the same font. I'll work up a MWE tomorrow.

Comment: You might want to `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` for this. Setting the beamerfonts `title` and `section` might work with your theme, but see what it uses internally.